# How do I fill a row entirely with a input field and button side by side?

Tags: html, css

css file

```
.columnForm {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

html file

```
<div class="row" style="height:100px;">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">          
            <form class="columnForm" name="columnForm">
                <label style="font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Add a new column</label>
                <div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="newcolumn"
                               name="newcolumn"
                               type="text"
                               ng-model="newcolumn"
                               class="form-control input-lg"
                               placeholder="enter a column name"
                               style="font-size:12px; float:left;" />
                        <button id="addButton"
                                name="addButton"
                                style="text-align:center; float:right"
                                ng-click="addColumn()"
                                class="btn btn-info form-control input-lg">
                            Add
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want them to cover an entire row side by side but this code above puts both of them on the left hand side of the screen one on the top of the other.

Comment: please provide proper css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough using `input-group` DIV as flex container and making the childs grow to fill all the space

```css
.input-group{
  display: flex
}

.input-group > #newcolumn {
  flex-grow: 2
}

.input-group > #addButton {
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:100px;">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">          
        <form class="columnForm" name="columnForm">
            <label style="font-size:12px; text-align:center;">Add a new column</label>
            <div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="newcolumn"
                           name="newcolumn"
                           type="text"
                           ng-model="newcolumn"
                           class="form-control input-lg"
                           placeholder="enter a column name"
                           style="font-size:12px; float:left;" />
                    <button id="addButton"
                            name="addButton"
                            style="text-align:center; float:right"
                            ng-click="addColumn()"
                            class="btn btn-info form-control input-lg">
                        Add
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want that any of the component take more space than the other, change the flex-grow of any of them

Info about how to use flexbox:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks it works now! Is it possible to give the input field a wider width?

Comment: thanks! I have updated the answer! Please mark it as correct if it's everything OK :)